# Unsplash jQuery plugin with callback functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my first attempt at a jQuery plugin and really doing anything with jQuery which isn't simple DOM manipulation or initialising another plugin!

I'm really keen to learn where I have gone wrong and improve on the code.

The code for the plugin is:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.unsplash = function(options, cbOnImageSelect) {
        var defaults = {
            apiRootURL: "https://api.unsplash.com", // root for API, should not need to be overridden                                                               
            searchTerm: '', // the search term the results will be relating to
            imagesToReturn: 6, // number of rows to output per page of results
            page: 1, // page of search results to display, will be 1 to start
            randomImagesToShow: 3, // number of images to display at the outset, 0 for none
            apiClientId: '6066a5f8e2e83faef343bdca81bd128aebccec5d601e8e27501b0f6375423477', // can be overridden for a client id per account
            orientation: 'landscape', // orientation of images to query for [landscape | portrait | squarish]
            source: '', // where the plugin is being called from
            cbOnImageSelect: $.noop
        };

        images = [];
        totalImageCount = 0;
        selectedImage = {};

        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        //return to avoid breaking chaining
        return this.each(function() {
            //clear any content in the unsplash search
            $('#unsplashSearch').empty();
            //add a search form
            $('#unsplashSearch').append('<div class="in_searchBox"><input type="text" name="us_searchTerm" id="us_searchTerm" value="" maxlength="50"><button type="submit" name="us_SearchBtn" id="us_SearchBtn"><span>Search</span></button></div>');
            //bind the search handler event to the button in the form
            $("#us_SearchBtn").bind("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //reset page back to 1 to avoid a new search starting on the wrong page.
                settings.page = 1;
                //set the settings search term to the new value
                settings.searchTerm = $('#us_searchTerm').val();
                searchAndPopulate(getSearchURL(settings.searchTerm, 1), settings.apiClientId);
            });
            $('#unsplashSearch').append('<ul id="imageList" class="horizontalList"></ul>');
            $('#unsplashSearch').append('<div id="us_Paging" style="text-align: center;"></div>');
            if (settings.randomImagesToShow > 0) {
                //build up the request url based on whether the search term is null or not...
                searchAndPopulate((!settings.searchTerm) ? getRandomURL(settings.randomImagesToShow) : getSearchURL(settings.searchTerm, 1), settings.apiClientId);
            } else {
                $('#us_Paging').hide();
            }

            //private functions
            function callUnsplash(url) {
                return $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    method: 'GET',
                    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Client-ID ' + settings.apiClientId);
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept-Version', 'v1');
                    },
                    success: function(json) {
                        totalImageCount = (json.hasOwnProperty('total')) ? json.total : settings.imagesToReturn;
                        images = (json.hasOwnProperty('results')) ? json.results : json;
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        alert("Sorry, something went wrong (" + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + ")");
                    }
                });
            }

            function searchAndPopulate(url, key) {
                var callUnsplashPromise = callUnsplash(url, key);
                callUnsplashPromise.done(populateImages);
            }

            function populateImages() {
                if (images.total == 0) {
                } else {
                    //clear any existing images in the list
                    $('#imageList').empty();
                    $.each(images, function(index, image) {
                        var liContent = `<li><a href="#" class="splashImage" data-photoid="${image.id}"><div class="in_max200"><img src='${image.urls.thumb}' class='in_singlepic in_max200'></a></li>`;
                        $('#imageList').append(liContent);
                    });
                    //bind the callback function to the splashImage so it is called when clicked. if no callback is provided, then the default will be performed
                    $(".splashImage").bind("click", function(event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        if (typeof settings.cbOnImageSelect == 'function') {
                            var photoId = $(this).data('photoid');
                            var url = getImageURL(photoId);
                            var getImagePromise = callUnsplash(url);
                            getImagePromise.done(function(i) {
                                settings.cbOnImageSelect.call(this, i);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    if (totalImageCount <= settings.imagesToReturn) {
                        $('#us_Paging').hide();
                    } else {
                        $('#us_Paging').empty().show();
                        if (totalImageCount > settings.imagesToReturn) {
                            var noOfPages = Math.ceil(totalImageCount / settings.imagesToReturn);
                            var x = pagination(settings.page, noOfPages);
                            for (var p = 0; p < x.length; p++) {
                                var linkText = ((x[p] !== '...') && (x[p] !== settings.page)) ? '<a href="##" class="us_changePage" data-page="' + x[p] + '">' + x[p] + '</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;' : x[p] + '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                                $('#us_Paging').append(linkText);
                            }
                            //add the click event to the buttons with the class us_changePage
                            $(".us_changePage").bind("click", function(event) {
                                event.preventDefault();
                                var nextPage = $(this).data('page');
                                settings.page = nextPage;
                                var nextURL = getSearchURL(settings.searchTerm, nextPage);
                                searchAndPopulate(nextURL, settings.apiClientId);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            function getSearchURL(searchTerm, pageToShow) {
                return settings.apiRootURL + '/search/photos?page=' + pageToShow + '&per_page=' + settings.imagesToReturn + '&orientation=' + settings.orientation + '&query=' + searchTerm;
            }

            function getRandomURL(numberOfImages) {
                return settings.apiRootURL + '/photos/random?count=' + numberOfImages + '&orientation=' + settings.orientation;
            }

            function getImageURL(photo_id) {
                return settings.apiRootURL + '/photos/' + photo_id;
            }

            function pagination(c, m) {
                var current = c,
                    last = m,
                    delta = 2,
                    left = current - delta,
                    right = current + delta + 1,
                    range = [],
                    rangeWithDots = [],
                    l;
                for (var i = 1; i <= last; i++) {
                    if (i == 1 || i == last || i >= left && i < right) {
                        range.push(i);
                    }
                }
                for (var i of range) {
                    if (l) {
                        if (i - l === 2) {
                            rangeWithDots.push(l + 1);
                        } else if (i - l !== 1) {
                            rangeWithDots.push('...');
                        }
                    }
                    rangeWithDots.push(i);
                    l = i;
                }
                return rangeWithDots;
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

A link to a demo on JSFiddle: [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/jaffakke/fwa7mh0d/4/)

Questions I have:

Is there a better way of maintaining the returned images JSON between the Ajax request and populating the page i.e.

```
images = [];
```

Have I bound the click event handlers correctly in the plugin; i.e.

```
$("#us_SearchBtn").bind("click", function(e) {
```

Also if you have any suggestions on how to run a different callback depending on which "Choose background" link is clicked, I'd be really grateful.

Answer (score 1):

> Questions I have:
>
> Is there a better way of maintaining the returned images JSON between
>   the Ajax request and populating the page i.e.
>
> `images = [];`

`images` is a value that can be removed from the global scope. The value is defined when the jQuery promise object returns a value

`images` variable is not necessary

Define a function to handle errors

```
  function handleError(error) {
    alert(error.message)
  }
```

`return` a value from `callUnsplash`

```
  function callUnsplash(url) {
    return $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      method: 'GET',
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Client-ID ' + settings.apiClientId);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept-Version', 'v1');
      },
      success: function(json) {
        totalImageCount = (json.hasOwnProperty('total')) ? json.total : settings.imagesToReturn;
        // `return` value here, which will be `images` parameter at `populateImages`
        return json.hasOwnProperty('results') ? json.results : json;
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        // throw error
        throw new Error("Sorry, something went wrong (" + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + ")");
      }
    });
  }
```

`images` is value `return`ed from `callUnsplash()`. `$.map()` can be substituted for `$.each()` for ability to `return` an HTML string or jQuery object when passed as parameter to `.append()`. Concatenate HTML strings where possible instead of calling `.append()` more than once chained to more than one `jQuery()` call. Include missing closing `</div>` where HTML is appended to `#imageList` unexpected results.

```
  function populateImages(images) {
    if (images.total == 0) {} else {
      //clear any existing images in the list
      $('#imageList').empty()
      .append($.map(images, function(image, index) {
        return `<li><a href="#" class="splashImage" data-photoid="${image.id}"><div class="in_max200"><img src='${image.urls.thumb}' class='in_singlepic in_max200'></div></a></li>`
      }));
      //bind the callback function to the splashImage so it is called when clicked. if no callback is provided, then the default will be performed
      $(".splashImage").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (typeof settings.cbOnImageSelect == 'function') {
          var photoId = $(this).data('photoid');
          var url = getImageURL(photoId);
          // use `.then()`, handle errors
          callUnsplash(url).then(function(i) {
            settings.cbOnImageSelect.call(this, i);
          }, handleError);
        }
      });
      if (totalImageCount <= settings.imagesToReturn) {
        $('#us_Paging').hide();
      } else {
        $('#us_Paging').empty().show();
        if (totalImageCount > settings.imagesToReturn) {
          var noOfPages = Math.ceil(totalImageCount / settings.imagesToReturn);
          var x = pagination(settings.page, noOfPages);
          for (var p = 0; p < x.length; p++) {
            var linkText = ((x[p] !== '...') && (x[p] !== settings.page)) ? '<a href="##" class="us_changePage" data-page="' + x[p] + '">' + x[p] + '</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;' : x[p] + '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
            $('#us_Paging').append(linkText);
          }
          //add the click event to the buttons with the class us_changePage
          $(".us_changePage").on("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var nextPage = $(this).data('page');
            settings.page = nextPage;
            var nextURL = getSearchURL(settings.searchTerm, nextPage);
            searchAndPopulate(nextURL, settings.apiClientId);
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Use `.then()` instead of `.done()`. Handle errors

```
  function searchAndPopulate(url, key) {
    callUnsplash(url, key)
    .then(populateImages, handleError);
  }
```

> Have I bound the click event handlers correctly in the plugin; i.e.
>
> `$("#us_SearchBtn").bind("click", function(e) {`

Substitute `.on()` for `.bind()` which is deprecated

> Also if you have any suggestions on how to run a different callback
>   depending on which "Choose background" link is clicked, I'd be really
>   grateful.

Not certain what is meant by "a different callback". If a different handle for the `click` event is meant logic can be included in the function passed to `.on()` where the `data-photoid="${image.id}"` of the clicked element can be evaluated to perform different tasks based on the `image.id` value. For example

```
if ($(this).data().photoid === "abc") {
  // do stuff
}
```

```js
(function($) {
  /*
   *  unsplash
   * 
   *  jQuery plugin to manage interaction with unsplash API
   * 
   *
   */
  $.fn.unsplash = function(options, cbOnImageSelect) {
    // defaults for the plugin, client ID can be provided on a init by init basis so that each client can have their own CLIENTID and therefore won't count towards
    // a common limit
    var defaults = {
      apiRootURL: "https://api.unsplash.com", // root for API, should not need to be overridden                                                               
      searchTerm: '', // the search term the results will be relating to
      imagesToReturn: 6, // number of rows to output per page of results
      page: 1, // page of search results to display, will be 1 to start
      randomImagesToShow: 3, // number of images to display at the outset, 0 for none
      apiClientId: '9371fe014143706ce089532bc0149f75e5672f1a07acdd1599d42461c73e0707', // can be overridden for a client id per account
      orientation: 'landscape', // orientation of images to query for [landscape | portrait | squarish]
      source: '', // where the plugin is being called from
      cbOnImageSelect: $.noop
    };

    // images = [];
    var totalImageCount = 0;
    var selectedImage = {};

    function handleError(error) {
      alert(error.message)
    }

    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    //return to avoid breaking chaining
    return this.each(function() {
      //clear any content in the unsplash search
      $('#unsplashSearch').empty()
        //add a search form
        .append('<div class="in_searchBox"><input type="text" name="us_searchTerm" id="us_searchTerm" value="" maxlength="50"><button type="submit" name="us_SearchBtn" id="us_SearchBtn"><span>Search</span></button></div>');
      //bind the search handler event to the button in the form
      $("#us_SearchBtn").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //reset page back to 1 to avoid a new search starting on the wrong page.
        settings.page = 1;
        //set the settings search term to the new value
        settings.searchTerm = $('#us_searchTerm').val();
        searchAndPopulate(getSearchURL(settings.searchTerm, 1), settings.apiClientId);
      });
      $('#unsplashSearch').append('<ul id="imageList" class="horizontalList"></ul>' +
        '<div id="us_Paging" style="text-align: center;"></div>');
      if (settings.randomImagesToShow > 0) {
        //build up the request url based on whether the search term is null or not...
        searchAndPopulate((!settings.searchTerm) ? getRandomURL(settings.randomImagesToShow) : getSearchURL(settings.searchTerm, 1), settings.apiClientId);
      } else {
        $('#us_Paging').hide();
      }

      //private functions
      function callUnsplash(url) {
        return $.ajax({
          url: url,
          dataType: 'json',
          method: 'GET',
          beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Client-ID ' + settings.apiClientId);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept-Version', 'v1');
          },
          success: function(json) {
            totalImageCount = (json.hasOwnProperty('total')) ? json.total : settings.imagesToReturn;
            return json.hasOwnProperty('results') ? json.results : json;
          },
          error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            throw new Error("Sorry, something went wrong (" + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + ")");
          }
        });
      }

      function searchAndPopulate(url, key) {
        callUnsplash(url, key)
          .then(populateImages, handleError);
      }

      function populateImages(images) {
        if (images.total == 0) {} else {
          //clear any existing images in the list
          $('#imageList').empty()
            .append($.map(images, function(image, index) {
              return `<li><a href="#" class="splashImage" data-photoid="${image.id}"><div class="in_max200"><img src='${image.urls.thumb}' class='in_singlepic in_max200'></div></a></li>`;
            }));
          //bind the callback function to the splashImage so it is called when clicked. if no callback is provided, then the default will be performed
          $(".splashImage").on("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (typeof settings.cbOnImageSelect == 'function') {
              var photoId = $(this).data('photoid');
              var url = getImageURL(photoId);
              callUnsplash(url).then(function(i) {
                settings.cbOnImageSelect.call(this, i);
              }, handleError);
            }
          });
          if (totalImageCount <= settings.imagesToReturn) {
            $('#us_Paging').hide();
          } else {
            $('#us_Paging').empty().show();
            if (totalImageCount > settings.imagesToReturn) {
              var noOfPages = Math.ceil(totalImageCount / settings.imagesToReturn);
              var x = pagination(settings.page, noOfPages);
              for (var p = 0; p < x.length; p++) {
                var linkText = ((x[p] !== '...') && (x[p] !== settings.page)) ? '<a href="##" class="us_changePage" data-page="' + x[p] + '">' + x[p] + '</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;' : x[p] + '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                $('#us_Paging').append(linkText);
              }
              //add the click event to the buttons with the class us_changePage
              $(".us_changePage").on("click", function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var nextPage = $(this).data('page');
                settings.page = nextPage;
                var nextURL = getSearchURL(settings.searchTerm, nextPage);
                searchAndPopulate(nextURL, settings.apiClientId);
              });
            }
          }
        }
      }

      function getSearchURL(searchTerm, pageToShow) {
        return settings.apiRootURL + '/search/photos?page=' + pageToShow + '&per_page=' + settings.imagesToReturn + '&orientation=' + settings.orientation + '&query=' + searchTerm;
      }

      function getRandomURL(numberOfImages) {
        return settings.apiRootURL + '/photos/random?count=' + numberOfImages + '&orientation=' + settings.orientation;
      }

      function getImageURL(photo_id) {
        return settings.apiRootURL + '/photos/' + photo_id;
      }

      function pagination(c, m) {
        var current = c,
          last = m,
          delta = 2,
          left = current - delta,
          right = current + delta + 1,
          range = [],
          rangeWithDots = [],
          l;
        for (var i = 1; i <= last; i++) {
          if (i == 1 || i == last || i >= left && i < right) {
            range.push(i);
          }
        }
        for (var i of range) {
          if (l) {
            if (i - l === 2) {
              rangeWithDots.push(l + 1);
            } else if (i - l !== 1) {
              rangeWithDots.push('...');
            }
          }
          rangeWithDots.push(i);
          l = i;
        }
        return rangeWithDots;
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fwa7mh0d/6/)

Comment: Thanks for the comments; when I say a different callback, I mean if you clicked on choose image on widget 1 and selecting an image it would run a different callback from clicking on choose image on widget 3 and selecting an image - even if all the chooseImage links were initialised with a single unsplash() call. So I guess putting the callback as a data attribute on the choose image link and using eval(). Is that bad practice and if so, is there a better way? thanks

Comment: @j4ffa By callback are you referring to the function set at `cbOnImageSelect`? `eval()` is not necessary.